# Change password of an account that is used by a service

Tags: wix

My `Wix` installed service is run in an user domain account. The user credentials (name+password) are hardcoded in the `ServiceInstall` element of my `Wix` file.

**Will the service stop working if the user changes his password?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the product is installed, there's no connection left between the account credentials user provided during the installation and the account itself. It's the same when you install a SQL database, provide the account for connection string and later on change that SQL server account password - the application won't connect any longer and you would have to modify the connection string.

Comment: This means the Service will stop working after a password change until I adapt the Service account manually?

Comment: @nabulke I think so. Just test it to be sure.